# Fetch data from html page using regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex, fetch

I am trying to fetch a price on a given page by using regular expressions, but the variable I use to store the fetched content is always empty. Can some one help me in writing the correct regular expression.

If the page is: http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/memory-cards/itmczcsrtvjeb6nr?pid=acccrrqzzsgnfgea&_l=sXQjsX87GxqrvKzhjuOrkw--&_r=n_2yuAC4xgh0SZTuulvAtw--&ref=af8ad0c4-62a2-4381-99d3-3ad8285e260b

I want to fetch price 260 from here.

Some html code of page for tags:

```
<span id="fk-mprod-our-id" class="price final-price our fksk-our">Rs.<span class="small-font"> </span>260</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

you could write more bulletproof parser using simplehtmldom - see http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/. For me it never failed to parse document.

You will end up with code like this

```
<?php
include_once '/path/to/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/memory-cards/itmczcsrtvjeb6nr?pid=acccrrqzzsgnfgea&_l=sXQjsX87GxqrvKzhjuOrkw--&_r=n_2yuAC4xgh0SZTuulvAtw--&ref=af8ad0c4-62a2-4381-99d3-3ad8285e260b');
foreach ($html->find('span.final-price') as $element) {
    echo $element->plaintext;
}
//will output "Rs. 260", unless page changes
```

Much cleaner code, though it's performance nightmare when compared to regexes

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that's the only time the `final-price` class is used, so this ought to work:

```
/final-price.+?>(\d+)</
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Currency might change depending on the IP/Country, i would have used Explode (am not so good at Regex)

```
//consider that $html contains the page source
$html = explode('<span class="price final-price our fksk-our" id="fk-mprod-our-id">', $html);
$html = explode("</span>', $html[1]);
$price = $html[1];
```

i hope that helps.